# Capture different keys in 2 separate tampermonkey scripts

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I can't figure out what I'm missing. I have 2 separate Tampermonkey scripts which run on every page that tries to capture their associated keystroke.  Each script will run different processes with their single keystroke. I realized with both of them enabled, it only activates the second one listed in the dashboard. How can I keep the 2 scripts separated while being able to have both active on all the pages.

For example these 2 separate scripts:

Script 1

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Ctrl Y Function
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing key stroke function
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.onkeyup = function(e){
        if (event.key == "y" && event.ctrlKey){
            console.log("Ctrl + Y pressed!")
        } //if (event.key == "y" && event.ctrlKey)
    } //window.onkeyup = function(e)
})(); //Main
```

Script 2

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Ctrl Q Function
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing key stroke function
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.onkeyup = function(e){
        if (event.key == "q" && event.ctrlKey){
            console.log("Ctrl + q pressed!")
        } //if (event.key == "q" && event.ctrlKey)
    } //window.onkeyup = function(e)
})(); //Main
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging around it seems it's not a problem with Tampermonkey but the way I implemented the key listener. The original way I tried seems to be replacing the onkeyup function but I really needed to add an extra listener.

Script 1

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Ctrl Y Function
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing key stroke function
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (event.key == "y" && event.ctrlKey){
            console.log("Ctrl + Y pressed!")
        } //if (event.key == "y" && event.ctrlKey)
    }, false); //document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) =>
})(); //Main
```

Script 2

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Ctrl Q Function
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing key stroke function
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (event.key == "q" && event.ctrlKey){
            console.log("Ctrl + q pressed!")
        } //if (event.key == "q" && event.ctrlKey)
    }, false); //document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) =>
})(); //Main
```